# Finding anti difference for a given expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given:

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n^2 +3n+2}$$

And am asked to find the anti difference (i.e: quantity which when differences over gives the expression)

So, I started by partial fractions

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{-1}{n+2} $$

Now the answer to this is:

$$ -\Delta \frac{1}{n+1}$$

But its wrong for some reason ( doesn't match with given answers)..

Options:

[image]

Comment: What difference is being used? Forward difference, backward difference, ...? What are the options? There's no way to specify what reason this answer is interpreted as wrong unless you clarify (telling us it doesn't match the given answers doesn't actually give any information).

Comment: Is the difference operator defined as a forward or backward difference?

Comment: Forward difference

Comment: what about the first answer $1-\frac 1{n+1}$ ? (the $1$ get cancelde in difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you denote $$b_n = -\frac{1}{n+1}$$

then $$b_{n+1}-b_n = a_n = \frac{1}{n^2 +3n+2}$$

So $b_n$ is the desired antidifference of $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $b_{n+1}-b_n = a_n$ then $b_n = b_0 + a_0 + \cdots + a_{n-1}$.
Since $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{-1}{n+2}$, the sum telescopes.